# Altering a column family in cassandra in a multiple node topology

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, datastax, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-cli

I'm having the following issue when trying to alter cassandra: 
I'm altering the table straight forward:

```
ALTER TABLE posts ADD is_black BOOLEAN;
```

on a single-node environment, both under EC2 server and on localhost everything work perfect - select, delete and so on.

When I'm altering on a cluster with 3 nodes - stuff are getting massy.
When I perform

```
select().all().from(tableName).where..
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: is_black is not a column defined in this metadata

    at com.datastax.driver.core.ColumnDefinitions.getAllIdx(ColumnDefinitions.java:273)

    at com.datastax.driver.core.ColumnDefinitions.getFirstIdx(ColumnDefinitions.java:279)

    at com.datastax.driver.core.ArrayBackedRow.getIndexOf(ArrayBackedRow.java:69)

    at com.datastax.driver.core.AbstractGettableData.getString(AbstractGettableData.java:137)
```

Apparently I'm not the only one who's having this behaviour:
[reference](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-560)

p.s -  drop creating the keyspace is not a possibility for me since I cannot delete the data contained in the table.

Comment: Can you query that column via cqlsh on all of your nodes?

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 yes I do, works on every node on every fermutation of data.

Comment: it might have something to do with the cached metadata for the datastax driver. Could you may be try to restart your application server to clear the cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug was resolved :-)

I issue was that DataStax maintains in memory cache that contains the configuration of each node, this cache wasn't update when I alter the table since I used cqlsh instead of their SDK.

After restarting all the node, the in memory cache was dropped and the bug was resolved.

Comment: Which version of the driver were you using? It is supposed to refresh its metadata, even if a third-party (like cqlsh) is making the schema changes (see http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/metadata/#refreshes). I'm having similar problems with the 2.1 driver.